# ServiceM8 webhook object types

Tags: api, webhooks

When [adding a new webhook subscription](http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/platform-services/webhooks/) for ServiceM8, the documentation mentions "object" as a parameter ("Indicates the object type that this subscription applies to"). However, it doesn't seem to mention the acceptable object types that can be passed in. What are the valid object types (strings) that can be used for webhook events? I just need to know what the available webhook events are for the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid object types are the same as the API endpoints listed here: http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/reference/

For example, "company", "job", "jobmaterial", "jobcontact" etc.